# How Consumer read the Data?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Suppose I send 10 data in Kafka topic , So kafka Consumer read 5 data from topic, So how Consumer knows that he have 5 more data to read ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumers are able to query each partition for the high watermark (greatest offset). The difference between its current position and that is called the lag, and is something you'll want to monitor.